# Python String or boolean in Crystal Reports - How to format headings in report

Tags: python, arrays, string, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-formulas

I am not very good at python but it seems I need to alter a python string to get the results I need but I am not sure how to do it. In crystal reports I can color this section using the section expert but then it colors all the main headings the same color. For example I have this:

```
    If {@GroupNumber} = 1 then "prepress" 
   else 
    if {@GroupNumber} = 2 then "stock" 
   else 
   if {@GroupNumber} = 3 then "press" 
   else 
   if {@GroupNumber} = 4 then "ink" 
   else 
   if {@GroupNumber} = 5 then "postpress"
```

Those are the different "groups" all utilizing the same header. It gives each section a different title but I need to find a way to specify each header in a different color. Any suggestions how I can get these headers color-coded?

```
if GroupNumber = 1 then fuchsia
else
If GroupNumber = 2 then yellow
else
If GroupNumber = 3 then yellow
else
If GroupNumber = 4 then yellow
else
If GroupNumber = 5 then green
```

Only my "press" heading is showing correct results. All the others are showing up black and I am not sure why.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood. Do you want to conditionally select the background color of a section in Crystal Reports? If so, use section expert, use the formula of background color and put the same formula there, but instead of the strings that you mentioned, just use the color constants (white, black, red, etc.) or RGB function like "rgb(255, 0, 0)".

Comment: Yes you understood correct. I have tried putting that formula in the section expert. It works for the first heading "prepress" but then all the other headings get blacked-out. Not sure why the first heading works perfectly and not the other four. Any ideas what could be wrong? I have used the color format "crFuchsia"—which works but "crYellow" and "crGreen" just come out as black bars.

Comment: The color is shown as black if (a) it is black; (b) it is invalid; (c) it is null. For example, if it does not fall in any of your if's, it will be null. Maybe you should print your {@GroupNumber} to check if it has the value that you expect.

Comment: I have tried printing it and it yields the same results. The other fields all show up black. The formula is correct for the wording—which is shown above, the colors are the only thing not working. Im not sure how to troubleshoot because I don't know crystal very well. It's either B or C but I am not sure

Comment: Are you really using "{@GroupNumber}" in first formula and "GroupNumber" in second formula? "{@GroupNumber}" is a formula written by you, while "GroupNumber" is a reserved word of Crystal Report. Are you aware of it?

Comment: No!! I was completely unaware of that information. Switching the second formula to "{@GroupNumber}" as well solved my issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For futher reference:

After the comments above, it seems the solution was to use the custom formula "{@GroupNumber}" instead of the reserved word "GroupNumber".

Though they have the same name, they refer to different things.